# Changing one entire column of invalid literals for floats in text file

Tags: python, numpy, io, data-conversion

A program finished running and produced an output text file, where I basically store the content of a 2D matrix.

The problem is that for some reason something went wrong in the run of the code, and as a result I am getting strange values for the entire second column of the file, which has "numbers" of this form `-0.526254956249307482-311`.

I wanted to replace that column, for example using

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.loadtxt("outputfile.txt", unpack=True)
matrix[1, :] = 0.
```

which should set the values of that column to 0 artificially, and I would be happy with that.

Unfortunately this method does not work, saying

```
invalid literal for float(): -0.526254956249307482-311
```

when it encounters the first "strange" number in the file. Any ideas?

I write here below a little excerpt from the file (the first three lines, just to show how it looks like)

```
    0.100000000000000111E-02   -0.526254956249307482-311 0.764784798622131334E+00    0.262873337864875811E+01    0.208378931879997231E-01    0.833944082260131836E+00   

    0.100000000000000111E-02   -0.526254956199900917-311    0.295833469629287749E+00    0.452671760320663452E+01    0.251516385376453384E-01    0.114372291564941397E+01   

    0.100000000000000111E-02   -0.526254956199900917-311    0.352831211090087915E+00    0.303885749578475917E+01    0.219180066883564000E-01    0.949515032768249556E+00
```

Comment: Process the file *before* attempting to load it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't know how! Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a custom converter for column at index `1` and just return a zero for all values:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.loadtxt('np_nan.txt', unpack=True, converters={1: lambda x: 0})
```

Now `matrix` is:

```
array([[  1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-03],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  7.64784799e-01,   2.95833470e-01,   3.52831211e-01],
       [  2.62873338e+00,   4.52671760e+00,   3.03885750e+00],
       [  2.08378932e-02,   2.51516385e-02,   2.19180067e-02],
       [  8.33944082e-01,   1.14372292e+00,   9.49515033e-01]])
```

You might also consider using NaN instead of zero:

```
matrix = np.loadtxt('np_nan.txt', unpack=True, converters={1: lambda x: np.nan})
```

Now `matrix` is:

```
array([[  1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-03],
       [             nan,              nan,              nan],
       [  7.64784799e-01,   2.95833470e-01,   3.52831211e-01],
       [  2.62873338e+00,   4.52671760e+00,   3.03885750e+00],
       [  2.08378932e-02,   2.51516385e-02,   2.19180067e-02],
       [  8.33944082e-01,   1.14372292e+00,   9.49515033e-01]])
```